# Mathcal in fouriernc package

Tags: mathcal

I like to use fouriernc package. But unfortunately the mathcal font in this package doesn't look nice to me and I would like to ask if it is possible to use this package while changing the mathcal font, say in mathpazo package.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `mathpazo.sty` we find

```
 \DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}   {symbols}
```

which sends us to

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}       {OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
```

You can then do

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{Zplm}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{bold}{OMS}{zplm}{b}{n}
```

See [`texdoc fntguide`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/fntguide.pdf) for more information. The second line is for the `\boldmath` version.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

This is math: $a+b\in\mathcal{F}(Z)$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the suggested declaration, we'd get

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have never used `mathpazo` before, but here's a possible solution

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]


\begin{equation}
\sin(x) = x + \mathcal{O}(x^3)
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably `cmsy` instead of `cmex`